Failed to spawn command 'username': No such file or directory (os error 2)
При открытии терминала выдает ошибку
username - имя пользователя
alacritty: Failed to spawn command 'username': No such file or directory (os error 2)
kitty:

Также заметил, что команда
echo $SHELL

выдает мне имя пользователя:
> echo $SHELL
username


возможно случайно удалили шел для входа который был прописан. Посмотрите список доступных, командой: chsh --list-shells, после выберите один из них и пропишите в конце команды chsh --shell ШЕЛ, например chsh --shell /bin/fish

Выдает ошибку "Вы не можете изменять командную оболочку у username"

а после чего у вас появились эти ошибки, не не пустом же месте ?
да и интересно что покажет команда grep $USER /etc/passwd
